# WebDAV OSX Permissions to restrict upload

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions

I have a WebDav server I have working on OSX ML - access is secure but I just moved my files to an external drive

1. I didn't need to modify directory permissions on the drive and it still works and requires password… is it still as secure?
2. How do I make an alias that doesn't require a password but will not allow uploads?

   - the access I gave now will allow GUEST but will also allow uploads?

The following are my access conf, and permissions on that drive:

```
drwxr-xr-x   6 iMac  staff    204 Feb  7 09:54 Download
drwxr-xr-x   5 iMac  staff    170 Feb  5 19:17 STORAGE
drwxr-xr-x   5 iMac  staff    170 Feb  5 19:14 WebDAV
```

-

```
# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
#
# Required modules: mod_dav, mod_dav_fs, mod_setenvif, mod_alias
#                   mod_auth_digest, mod_authn_file
#

# The following example gives DAV write access to a directory called
# "uploads" under the ServerRoot directory.
#
# The User/Group specified in httpd.conf needs to have write permissions
# on the directory where the DavLockDB is placed and on any directory where
# "Dav On" is specified.

DavLockDB "/usr/var/DavLock"

Alias /webdav "/xyz/WebServer/WebDAV"

<Directory "/xyz/WebServer/WebDAV">
Dav On
Options Indexes MultiViews

Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
# Add the following line to restrict access to Read or write
Require valid-user

AuthType Digest
AuthName DAV-upload

# You can use the htdigest program to create the password database:
#   htdigest -c "/usr/user.passwd" DAV-upload admin
AuthUserFile "/xyz/uxyz.passwd"
AuthDigestProvider file

# Allow universal read-access, but writes are restricted
# to the admin user.
<LimitExcept GET OPTIONS>
    require user admin
</LimitExcept>
</Directory>


Alias /webdav-private "/Volumes/RAID_MIRROR/WebDAV"

<Directory "/Volumes/RAID_MIRROR/WebDAV">
Dav On
Options Indexes MultiViews

Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
AuthType Digest
AuthName DAV-Public
AuthUserFile "/xyz/xyz.passwd"
AuthDigestProvider file
<LimitExcept GET OPTIONS>
    #require user public
</LimitEx# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)

Alias /download "/Volumes/RAID_MIRROR/Download"

<Directory "/Volumes/RAID_MIRROR/Download">
Dav On
Options Indexes MultiViews

Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

On the actual web server (OSX) (not the external drive) I am using different permissions to allow apache to access by the group _www but the external doesn't require this restriction?

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    68 Jun 20  2012 CGI-Executables
drwxr-xr-x  14 root  wheel   476 Jan 20  2013 Documents
drwxrwxrwx  29 _www  _www    986 Jan 21 12:24 WebDAV
drwxrwxrwx  24 _www  _www    816 Mar 18  2013 WebDAV-Public
```